# How to write a python function based on set of conditions

Tags: python, function

I have hundreds of project entries that I am trying to write a function to calculate the time spent in a project stage during a given month only.

I have an entry for the project every time there is a project stage change. The clock starts at the beginning of the month or when the StageID is 2. And ends at the end of the month or when the StageID is 3.

How do I calculate the time a project spends in StageID 2 between the specified start_date and end_date using the dataframe below?

```
start_date = pd.to_datetime('2021-07-01 00:00:00.000')
end_date = pd.to_datetime('2021-07-31 23:59:59.999')

df = pd.DataFrame({'ProjectID': [1,1,2,2],
                 'StageID' : [2,3,2,3,],
                 'Date' : ["2021-7-2", "2021-7-28", "2021-7-15", "2021-8-22"]})
```

I expect the result to look like:

```
        ProjectID    DaysPassed
     0      1           26
     1      2           16
```

Bonus questions:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({'ProjectID': [1,1,1,1,2,2],
                     'StageID' : [2,3,2,3,2,3,],
                     'Date' : ["2021-7-5", "2021-7-10","2021-7-15","2021-7-20", "2021-7-15", "2021-8-22"]})
```

expect the result to look like:

```
        ProjectID    DaysPassed
     0      1           10
     1      2           16
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you are expecting to see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you want:

```
output = df[df["StageID"].eq(2)].drop("StageID", axis=1).merge(df[df["StageID"].eq(3)].drop("StageID", axis=1), on="ProjectID")
output["DaysPassed"] = output["Date_y"].clip(upper=pd.Timestamp(2021,7,31)).sub(output["Date_x"])
output = output.drop(["Date_x", "Date_y"],axis=1)

>>> df
   ProjectID DaysPassed
0          1    26 days
1          2    16 days
```

If your projects can have multiple iterations, you can create a new column to identify the project uniquely:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ProjectID': [1,1,1,1,2,2], 
                   'StageID' : [2,3,2,3,2,3,], 
                   'Date' : ["2021-7-5", "2021-7-10","2021-7-15","2021-7-20", "2021-7-15", "2021-8-22"]})

df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
df["Iteration"] = df.groupby(["ProjectID", "StageID"])["Date"].cumcount()+1
output = df[df["StageID"].eq(2)].drop("StageID", axis=1).merge(df[df["StageID"].eq(3)].drop("StageID", axis=1), on=["ProjectID", "Iteration"])
output["DaysPassed"] = output["Date_y"].clip(upper=pd.Timestamp(2021,7,31)).sub(output["Date_x"]).dt.output = output.drop(["Date_x", "Date_y"],axis=1)

>>> output
   ProjectID  Iteration  DaysPassed
0          1          1           5
1          1          2           5
2          2          1          16
```

Comment: Except if the end date falls beyond the end_date of 2021-07-31 then it would use the end_date instead to calculate duration. So for ProjectID 2 StageID 2 it would be 16 days and not 38 days. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you so much, that answered my questions.  Would you be able to help me one step further? What if a project went from project stage 2 to 3 back to 2 to 3? How would I calculate the time only between project stages 2 and 3? 'df = pd.DataFrame({'ProjectID': [1,1,1,1,2,2],
                 'StageID' : [2,3,2,3,2,3,],
                 'Date' : ["2021-7-5", "2021-7-10","2021-7-15","2021-7-20", "2021-7-15", "2021-8-22"]})'

Comment: Please refrain from asking follow-up questions in the comments. I have edited my answer this time, but for future reference, new question=new post.